# Variable en query

Tags: asp, gridview

estoy haciendo un tablon de notas con asp. Y tengo un problema que he intentado solucionar de mil maneras pero no encuentro la solución.

Si a la query le pongo el id de la toma a mano se muestra el gridview correctamente:

```
  Dim b As String = nodoSel.Value
    Dim numero As String = b.Split("_"c)(0)

    Dim connectionString As String = " "
    Dim query As String = "SELECT id, id_toma, notas, fecha_nota FROM [notas] WHERE id_toma = 205"

    Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        connection.Open()

        Using selectCommand As New SqlCommand(query, connection)
            selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Numero", numero)

            Dim notasTable As New DataTable()
            notasTable.Load(selectCommand.ExecuteReader())

            If notasTable.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                GridViewNotas.DataSource = notasTable
                GridViewNotas.DataBind()
            End If
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si a la query (que es como quiero hacerlo) le sustituyo el 205 por la variable Numero, el gridview desaparece. El modal sigue saliendo correctamente y me deja guardar las notas y todo. Es más, depurando me he dado cuenta que la tabla se sigue creando correctamente lo que pasa de no se pinta en la web.

```
Protected Sub CargarNotasGuardadas()
    Dim b As String = nodoSel.Value
    Dim numero As String = b.Split("_"c)(0)

    Dim connectionString As String = " "
    Dim query As String = "SELECT id, id_toma, notas, fecha_nota FROM [notas] WHERE id_toma = @Numero"

    Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        connection.Open()

        Using selectCommand As New SqlCommand(query, connection)
            selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Numero", numero)

            Dim notasTable As New DataTable()
            notasTable.Load(selectCommand.ExecuteReader())

            If notasTable.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                GridViewNotas.DataSource = notasTable
                GridViewNotas.DataBind()
            End If
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

EDICIÓN: Añado imagen de lo que me devuelve la variable
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Verificaste si luego de hacer la asignación a _numero_ (`Dim numero As String = b.Split("_"c)(0)`), tal variable tiene algún valor? No olvides depurar siempre tu código.

Comment: Si tiene, como he comentado la tabla se crea correctamente pero no se muestra el gridView en la web. Al llegar a `GridViewNotas.DataSource = notasTable
                GridViewNotas.DataBind() ` la tabla está correctamente cargada

Comment: ¿Se muestra algún error en la consola del navegador?

Comment: No, no se muestra ni en la consola del navegador ni en la de depuración

Comment: Pruena poner `Dim numero As String = "205"` a ver que pasa

Comment: Se muestra el gridview correctamente